# No Instance of Constructor "Class:Class" matches argument list

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to understand constructors and inheritance in C++ by doing the following exercise:

> Write a program that defines a shape class with a constructor that gives value to width and height. The define two sub-classes triangle and rectangle, that calculate the area of the shape area (). In the main, define two variables a triangle and a rectangle and then call the area() function in this two variables.

My attempt writing a constructor:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
    double width, height;
public:
    // Define constructor
    Shape(double newWidth, double newHeight):
        width{newWidth}, height{newHeight} {}
    // Define getters
    double getWidth() const
    {
        return width;
    }
    double getHeight() const
    {
        return height;
    }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height);
    }
};

class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height)/2;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Rectangle rect(5.0,3.0);
    Triangle tri(2.0,5.0);
    cout << rect.area() << endl;
    cout << tri.area() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
no instance of constructor "Rectangle::Rectangle" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (double, double)
```

I think the error comes from how I instantiate both `rect` and `tri` but I can't seem to solve the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't written any contructor => do that :) , it's up to you to create the function `Rectangle(double q, double b) { //stuff } `

Comment: Also, notice that `rect()` and `tri()` don't exist in your code

Comment: Have you considered polymorphism, making `area` into a pure virtual that must be implemented in the derived classes, like `virtual double area() const = 0;`?

Comment: Does this problem persist if you remove the triangle class? If not, remove it to get closer to a [mcve].

Answer (score 12):

Constructors are not inherited. If you want to inherit the constructor you can:

```cpp
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
  using Shape::Shape;

  // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you instanciate your `rect`and `tri` variables with two arguments (`Triangle(double, double)` and `Rectangle(double,double)`), thus you need to define these constructors with two arguments in your derived classes. Currently, you have not defined constructor with `(double,double)` arguments for your derived classes `Triangle` and `Rectangle`.

Your error comes from the fact that, when the body of the derived class constructor is run, it first invokes the default (no-argument) constructor for its base class.

As you already have a `Shape(double,double)`  constructor with arguments and have not defined a no-argument `Shape()`constructor, then it fails to compile.

To solve your error, you need to use `Initialization lists` of your `Triangle` and `Rectangle`constructors, which allow you to choose which base class constructor is called and what arguments that constructor should receive. More document [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Here is my code attempt

```cpp
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
    //create a Triangle constructor and call base class with its arguments
    Rectangle(double lWidth, double l_Height):Shape(lWidth,l_Height)
    {

    }
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height);
    }
};

class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
    //create a Triangle constructor and call base class with its arguments
    Triangle(double lWidth, double l_Height): Shape(lWidth,l_Height)
    {

    }
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height)/2;
    }
};
```